# VBA VLOOKUP gives an Object Required error

Tags: excel, vba

Below VBA Code is working fine if **FindVal** is a Text value.

**1. Working For String Value**

```
Private Sub FDACNo_Change()
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Worksheets("FD Accounts").Range("FDAccountData")
On Error Resume Next
FindVal = FDACNo
Names.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FindVal, myRange, 2, False)
If err.Number <> 0 Then Names.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Afterthat I changed this code (Diclare Dim FindVal as Long) to use this code for Numeric Value. Like below.

**2. Not Working For Numerical Values**

```
Private Sub FDACNo_Change()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim FindVal As Long
Set myRange = Worksheets("FD Accounts").Range("FDAccountData")
On Error Resume Next
FindVal = FDACNo
Names.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FindVal, myRange, 2, False)
If err.Number <> 0 Then Names.Value = ""
End Sub
```

But it gives me an Object Required Error Message.

**Note:** **FDACNo** and **Names** are name of two **TextBox** fields in a **UserFor**.

**FDACNo** is a numerical value, so I used **CStr(FindVal)** to convert it to a String Value like this:

```
Names.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CStr(FindVal), myRange, 2, False)
```

But no luck

Please Help.

Comment: You don't use `Set` with data values. Use `FindVal = FDACNo`

Comment: As stated above, `FindVal` not being an object, it is a mistake to `Set` it. This code returned the error. Besides that, since you could find strings in the same range, it mai be working as you try or not, **if the range in discussion is formatted As text**. In such a case you should use `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CStr(FindVal),...`.

Comment: Hey @FaneDuru, how are you? good to see you. I don't know how but **Cdbl** solved my problem. Anyway, Thanks for giving me an great Idea **CStr**.